# Arm Assembly - Calling function with more than 4 arguments

Tags: assembly, stack, arm, disassembly

I know that when calling a function in assembly r0 contains the first argument up to r3 being the fourth. I know that when it goes beyond four the stack pointer is used but I'm not too sure on the specifics. Does r0-r3 still hold the first four and the rest goes on the stack? I'm looking at the following piece of assembly trying to understand what it's doing to call mach_msg (a function with seven arguments). On entry to this code, r0 and r1 contain the two arguments

```
var_38          = -0x38
var_34          = -0x34
var_30          = -0x30
var_2C          = -0x2C
var_24          = -0x24
var_20          = -0x20
var_18          = -0x18
var_14          = -0x14
var_10          = -0x10
var_C           = -0xC
00001220
00001220                 PUSH            {R7,LR}
00001222                 MOV             R7, SP
00001224                 SUB             SP, SP, #0x30
00001226                 MOV             R2, (_NDR_record_ptr - 0x1232) ; _NDR_record_ptr
0000122E                 ADD             R2, PC ; _NDR_record_ptr
00001230                 LDR             R2, [R2] ; _NDR_record
00001232                 LDR             R3, [R2]
00001234                 LDR             R2, [R2,#4]
00001236                 STR             R2, [SP,#0x38+var_10]
00001238                 MOVS            R2, #0x24 ; '$'
0000123A                 STR             R3, [SP,#0x38+var_14]
0000123C                 MOVS            R3, #0
0000123E                 STRB.W          R1, [SP,#0x38+var_C]
00001242                 MOVS            R1, #0x13
00001244                 STR             R1, [SP,#0x38+var_2C]
00001246                 MOVS            R1, #1
00001248                 STR             R0, [SP,#0x38+var_24]
0000124A                 MOV             R0, 0x1E84EA
00001252                 STR             R3, [SP,#0x38+var_20]
00001254                 STR             R3, [SP,#0x38+var_38]
00001256                 STR             R3, [SP,#0x38+var_34]
00001258                 STR             R0, [SP,#0x38+var_18]
0000125A                 STR             R3, [SP,#0x38+var_30]
0000125C                 ADD             R0, SP, #0x38+var_2C
0000125E                 BLX             _mach_msg
00001262                 ADD             SP, SP, #0x30
00001264                 POP             {R7,PC}
```

Here are the definitions for the stuff being called and used:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char       mig_vers;
    unsigned char       if_vers;
    unsigned char       reserved1;
    unsigned char       mig_encoding;
    unsigned char       int_rep;
    unsigned char       char_rep;
    unsigned char       float_rep;
    unsigned char       reserved2;
} NDR_record_t;
extern NDR_record_t NDR_record;
extern mach_msg_return_t    mach_msg(
                mach_msg_header_t *msg,
                mach_msg_option_t option,
                mach_msg_size_t send_size,
                mach_msg_size_t rcv_size,
                mach_port_name_t rcv_name,
                mach_msg_timeout_t timeout,
                mach_port_name_t notify);
```

From what I understand, the stack pointer is being reversed 48 bytes for variables. Is that 48 bytes for the extra 3 arguments or for all of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of the 48 bytes, 12 are for the extra 3 parameters, and the others are for local variables. You can see this in the code where the function passes four parameters in r0 through r3, another in [SP,#0x38+var_38] (which if you do the math resolves to just [sp]), another in [sp,#4], and the last in [sp,#8].

Comment: So do the remaining arguments start from the beginning of the stack pointer?

Comment: Right, that's what `[sp]` means.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int fun
(
    unsigned int a,
    unsigned int b,
    unsigned int c,
    unsigned int d,
    unsigned int e,
    unsigned int f
)
{
    a+=1;
    a|=b+2;
    a&=c+4;
    a^=d+5;
    a-=e+6;
    a|=~f;
    return(a);
}


00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
   4:   e2811002    add r1, r1, #2
   8:   e181c000    orr ip, r1, r0
   c:   e2822004    add r2, r2, #4
  10:   e002100c    and r1, r2, ip
  14:   e59d0000    ldr r0, [sp]
  18:   e2833005    add r3, r3, #5
  1c:   e023c001    eor ip, r3, r1
  20:   e59d1004    ldr r1, [sp, #4]
  24:   e060200c    rsb r2, r0, ip
  28:   e2420006    sub r0, r2, #6
  2c:   e1e03001    mvn r3, r1
  30:   e1800003    orr r0, r0, r3
  34:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

The first four are r0 = a, r1 = b, r2 = c, r3 - d, in order, and then the rest are pushed in reverse order so that sp+0 is e and sp+4 is f.

If you have say a 64 bit integer then that will take two registers, so you could use up r0-r3 with four ints or two ints and a long long, or two long longs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

i remember, as many as can be passed through registers(r0-r3 or 4 words) are passed via registers. and the rest are passed through the stack.